Renderdoc crash on compute shader debug with more bindings than required
Graphics: Vulkan (Godot 3.4 - C# edition)
Problem:
I have multiple classes responsible for different compute shaders and uniform sets.
I sometimes need to use one class' uniform set in another's compute shader, so for now, I just bind all uniform sets every time I run a compute shader.
The program runs fine when doing this, but renderdoc is unable to debug the compute shader if I do this.
When I click on "debug" for a compute shader with more binded uniform sets than required by the shader, Renderdoc crashes.
Question:
Is binding more buffers / uniform sets than declared in the shader undefined behaviour?
Or is this a bug within Renderdoc?
Note:
I confirmed this was the problem causing the crash as, when I cull down the number of bindings to only those required by the shader, debugging works perfectly fine.

I don't know the answer, but:
This discussion suggests that it is OK to bind more than the shader uses.
Also, the RenderDoc author's GitHub would be a good place to ask.  If you don't want to open an issue there, the author gives you several ways to contact him.  This seems to be a legitimate case that RenderDoc should handle.
